# Username authentification with symmetric key working locally but not in remote server

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws

I have a jax-ws web service developped using netbeans 7 and glassfish 3.1.2 .
I configured the web service to use Username authentication with symmetric keys security and default keystore. 
When I test my web service in localhost everything work fine but when I delployed it in remote test server it didnt' work . 
First I got exception complaining about `Key used to decrypt EncryptedKey cannot be null` so I uploaded the local keystore.jks and cacerts.jks to the remote server.

Now I'm gettinh those exceptions:

**Server side:**

```
WSITPVD0035: Error in Verifying Security in Inbound Message. com.sun.xml.wss.impl.PolicyViolationException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Invalid Security Header at 
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.policy.verifier.MessagePolicyVerifier.verifyPolicy(MessagePolicyVerifier.java:151) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.createMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:1003) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:248) at 
com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.verifyInboundMessage(WSITServerAuthContext.java:588) at 
com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.validateRequest(WSITServerAuthContext.java:361) at 
com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthContext.validateRequest(WSITServerAuthContext.java:264) at 
com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:173) at 
com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:144) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:961) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:910) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:873) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:775) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:386) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:263) at 
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:120) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:91) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:200) at 
org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:131) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletAdapter.java:1059) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter$FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(ServletAdapter.java:999) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:434) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:384) at 
com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179) at 
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117) at 
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) at 
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228) at 
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) at 
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) at 
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) at 
com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) at 
com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) at 
com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) at 
com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at 
com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) at 
com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: Invalid Security Header at 
com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.SOAPUtil.newSOAPFaultException(SOAPUtil.java:159) at 
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.policy.verifier.MessagePolicyVerifier.processSecondaryPolicy(MessagePolicyVerifier.java:220) at 
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.policy.verifier.MessagePolicyVerifier.verifyPolicy(MessagePolicyVerifier.java:144) ... 43 more
```

**Client side:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Invalid Security Header
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:123)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:144)
```

How can i fix this ?

Thanks .

Comment: Do You have any reference on how you build the client application in the first place using Username Authentication with Symmetric Keys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace does not look familiar to me but **maybe your problem is the certificate itself**.

When you create a certificate you should set a 'server name'. This will be used by the client to check if the *certificate's 'server name' match with the URL 'server name'*. If the server names does not match the client should abort the connection because it can be an stolen certificate!!!. For more info, check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/index.html)

> **Example with a java client:** if you create a certificate for `'localhost'` the client
>   verification will pass if and only if it access the web service using an URL
>   like `'https://localhost/stuff...'`. So, if you tries to access the same application with the same client but using the IP like `'https://10.0.0.1/stuff...'`, a verification error should arise.

*NOTE: The default configuration of a java web service client do this check, but If you want to bypass this client side verification please check [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-bypass-certificate-checking-in-a-java-web-service-client/)*

Try to check if this is the problem you are having. If it is the case you have several solutions:

- Create a certificate for the server where you are deploying the
  application
- Disable client side verification

*PS: I never did something special on the server-side to solve this kind of issues. Installing the correct certificate should be enough*

Comment: Do you think that something is missing in the webs ervice's client description ?

Comment: No, is not about the web service client descriptor, is how its validate the certificate. Actually this is not only related to web service clients but any HTTP client. Try to execute the local test that works for you but instead of using `localhost` in the endpoint URL on your client, use the IP of your machine. If you get the same error the problem is around the certificate generation and not from your web service definition/implementation.

Comment: Ip access to the webservice failed because bizarrely glassfish was inaccessible with the real ip . I tried with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and it worked.

Comment: If it works with 127.0.0.1 maybe your problem is not the certificate server name. But to be sure if I were you, I would test again in the 'test server' with a certificate that match the server IP.

Comment: How can i generate a certificate with the server ip ?Do I have to creat an x509 or an ssl one ?

Comment: You can use `keytool` to generate the x509 certificate and import it to the server store. Check the tutorial that I mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in CommandMap. Need to add "application/ciphervalue" handler in CommandMap, because WSIT does it only once while loading CVDataHandler class.

See com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.CVDataHandler static block for more details how to add.